How can I add timeouts for each iteration inside a python os.walk loop?
I have the following def that stats all the directories on a server:
def collectAllDirectories():
    fullDirList = []
    w = walk(parent_dir, topdown=True)
    # Get a complelte list of directories and files and add tem to a list
    # Don't add them to the list if they have an omit exception.
    for (dirpath) in w:
       #print(dirpath[0])
    return fullDirList

Some paths contain hundreds of thousands of files. In those cases, I would like to skip that directory and stat the next one. I tried something like this:
def doThingWithTimeout(dirpath):
    global thread_finished
    print(dirpath[0])
    fullDirList.append(dirpath)
    thread_finished.set()  # Set the event to indicate that the thread has finished

def walkWithTimeout(parent_dir, timeout_per_iteration=30):  # Default timeout per iteration is 30 sec
    global thread_finished
    w = walk(parent_dir, topdown=True)
    for (dirpath) in w:
        thread_finished.clear()  # Clear the event before starting the thread
        # Start a new thread for each iteration
        t = threading.Thread(target=doThingWithTimeout, args=(dirpath,))
        t.start()
        # Wait for the thread to finish or timeout
        thread_finished.wait(timeout_per_iteration)
        if not thread_finished.is_set():  # If the thread has not finished within the timeout
            print("Timed out while processing:", dirpath)
            # Optionally handle the timeout here
            continue  # Move to the next directory
        t.join()  # Wait for the thread to finish before proceeding

But it doesn't seem to ever hit the timeout threshold despite stat-ing a directory for more than 30 seconds. I'm new to multithreading, so I'm sure I'm doing something wrong (and I used AI to help with the above). Does anyone know how to add timeouts to each directory inside a os.walk loop?
